# Streaming audio to ESP8266 over WiFi

Tags: esp8266

I am thinking of making a wireless speaker using the ESP8266 chip. I have some questions regarding this.

1. Which pin of the ESP8266 chip can be used as I²S output? I have an ESP chip of this type :
   [image]
2. Which ESP chip would be the best choice for this purpose?
3. I know about the MAX98357A which is used to convert digital I²S data to analog. But, for stereo output I need to use 2 of those. Is there any alternative to this chip which supports stereo output by default?
4. I have found many tutorials which shows how to play audio from SD card of ESP8266. But, how can I stream audio over standard WiFi connection?

Answer (score 2):

> Which pin of the ESP8266 chip can be used as I²S output?

I uses GPIOs 2, 3, and 15. You only have GPIO2 available, and that's also one half of the UART interface.  Also you usually need to generate a "master" clock (usually something like 256x the bit clock) for oversampling. So you can't with that module.

> Which ESP chip would be the best choice for this purpose?

ESP32, without a shadow of a doubt.

> I know about the MAX98357A which is used to convert digital I²S data to analog. But, for stereo output I need to use 2 of those. Is there any alternative to this chip which supports stereo output by default?

Yes, there are plenty. The search term you want is "CODEC". Personally I use the TLV320DAC3101.

You never use two separate mono CODECs for stereo, since I²S is a (normally) stereo protocol for connecting to a stereo CODEC. Reliably splitting a stereo I²S stream into two mono ones is not easy.

> I have found many tutorials which shows how to play audio from SD card of ESP8266. But, how can I stream audio over standard WiFi connection?

By implementing a suitable protocol, and that depends entirely on what your audio is and how it is generated.

Comment: For number 3 I am thinking of this technique : https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/295889/using-two-mono-amplifiers-to-make-one-stereo-amplifier

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the last answer? I simply want to stream MP3 audio.

Comment: There is no such thing as "simply" streaming MP3. Streaming involves buffering, then decoding (in a timely manner) the audio from compressed MP3 format into a PCM format. Then feeding that through other buffers to the I²S hardware. If you are streaming a live stream (radio, for example) then you have to be able to cleanly handle "xruns" (buffer under- or over-runs) where the sender isn't sending at the same speed as you're playing. So your project really comprises three parts: 1. Getting the data. 2. Decoding the data. 3. Sending the data to I²S. All three of those are difficult tasks.

Comment: What did you mean by **usually something like 256x the bit clock) for oversampling. So you can't with that module.**?

Comment: You don't have the required pins available. So you can't with that module. On top of that you have to usually generate a master clock. And there's no pin for that on that module. So you can't with that module. You just can't with that module.

Comment: Will the ESP32 be able to fulfil **all** those requirements?

Comment: More than likely, yes. Google for some projects.